# Entity framework Core One to Many without use of collections, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm having problems creating from code-first a structure in the database like the following:

```
dbo.Glasses
____________
|Id(PK) | LeftSideId(FK)-Nullable | RightSideId(FK)-Nullable|

dbo.Sides
____________
|Id(PK) | Value|
```

Classes

```
public class Glass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? LeftSideId {get;set;}
    public Side LeftSide {get;set;}
    public int? RightSideId {get;set;}
    public Side RightSide {get;set;}
}

public class Side
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string  Value {get;set;}
    public int Glass {get;set;}
    public Glass Glass {get;set;} 

}
```

What I tried with Fluent API (It's mandatory I use FluentApi):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Side>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(side => side.Glass)
        .WithOne(glass => glass.LeftSide)
        .HasForeignKey<Glass>(glass => glass.LeftSideId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.ClientSetNull);

    entity.HasOne(side => side.Glass)
        .WithOne(glass => glass.RightSide)
        .HasForeignKey<Glass>(glass => glass.RightSideId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.ClientSetNull);
});
```

With this I get the error:  `Cannot create a relationship between 'Side.Glass' and 'Glass.RightSide ', because there already is a relationship between 'Side.Glass' and 'Glass.LeftSide '.   Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.`

Comment: Not sure in this particular situation but you might want to check out shadow properties, might help you out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible, without a collection it will be an one-to-one relation

Try this

```
public class Side
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string  Value {get;set;}
  
    public virtual ICollection<Glass> LeftSideGlasses {get;set;} 
    public virtual ICollection<Glass> RightSideGlasses {get;set;} 
}
```

but if you still want one-to-one

```
public class Side
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string  Value {get;set;}
  
    public virtual Glass LeftSideGlass {get;set;} 
    public virtual Glass RightSideGlass {get;set;} 
}
```

or if you use only one LeftSideGlass or RightSideGlass  maybe it can make sense instead of 2 properties use the one only. You can just add a bool flag "IsLeft" for example.

Comment: *"if you use net core..."*. "net core"? what's the relation of net core and the issue? EF Core and Net Core are different things, and the question is clearly tagged `[entity-framework-core]`, hence the approach is always applicable, so don't see why you include that statement. Also don't forget that having more than one navigation to the same entity type won't work w/o additional configuration (either fluent or with attributes), so both your examples won't work as posted.

Comment: @IvanStoev I mean "old" ef6 doesn't support    public virtual Glass RightSideGlass {get;set;} , only public virtual ICollection<Glass> RightSideGlasses {get;set;}  can be used

Comment: I understand. But the question **is for** EF Core, hence what does EF6 (or Linq-to-Sql or any other ORM) is irrelevant. "if you use..." - they **do** use it :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, you are right, Thank you. When a question has too many chars I am too lazy to read it carefully. And I am usually don't read headers at all. I should pay more attention to them.

Comment: @Serge I've seen you give comments like this more often. I really like you recognizing and admitting it (really). But then I wonder, why oh why do you keep firing away these quick cursory (and often clearly untested, because incorrect) answers if you're aware of this shortcoming? I suggest you take a look in [meta] and find some stories on how other users experience these "Fastest Guns in the West".